# Reference of a function return value

Tags: c++

Suppose I have something like this

```
  class HandleInterface {
        GLuint handle_;
    protected:
        void SetHandle( GLuint i ) {
            handle_ = i;
        }

    public:
        GLuint GetHandle() const {
            return handle_;
        }

        virtual ~HandleInterface() {}
};
```

Buw now I need the reference of handle_.

```
// I would need &handle_
glGenBuffers( 1,&handle_ );
```

Do I need to write another getter for my `handle_`? Or how would get the reference of `handle_` from my getter method?

Also `glGenBuffers` somehow violates my `SetHandle` method because it should only set `handle_` though the `SetHandle` method and not though an reference. Any Ideas how I can avoid this?

Comment: Do you have any real reason to use the getter and setter? Is there  (or will there be) some invariant you need to maintain? It doesn't look like it currently.

Comment: No I just thought getter and setter are good practice, but at the moment I believe that it might not be the bester idea to use getter and setter here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep `handle_` fully encapsulated, pass a local variable to `glGenBuffers`:

```
GLuint handle;
glGenBuffers(1, &handle);
SetHandle(handle);
```